# Orthonormal basis of polynomial space wrt $\langle f, g\rangle = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\ dx$

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, orthogonal-polynomials

Does the polynomial sequence of orthonormal polynomials with respect to the inner product $\langle f, g\rangle = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\ dx$ of increasing degree have a name?  It doesn't seem to be the Legendre polynomials or Jacobi polynomials, but maybe someone else has their name on it.

Explicitly, here's the first few terms: $$\big(1, \sqrt{12}(x-\frac 12), 6\sqrt{5}(x^2-x+\frac 16), \cdots\big)$$

PS, if the answer is no, then I call dibs on the Bobbie D polynomials. ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the shifted Legendre polynomials

Comment: I see.  Thanks!$ $

Comment: There is a closed expression for them, too, you can find aome info on the wikipedia page.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at that now.  It's easier to find once you know the name.  Thanks, again. :)